# Can you save text files using PascalABC.NET?

Tags: game-engine, pascal

e.g. have a line be saing "save ('hp=30,x=3,y=74,mode=7')=save.txt"
and after executing it there will be a text file named "save" in the folder with the executable, and will contain "hp=30,x=3,y=74,mode=7", is that possible? And is it possible to "load" it so it will give specified silible its content?

Comment: If you can't find a task for doing this amongst the 1100 examples mentioned on http://ptaskbook.com/en/index.php, consider using a different Pascal implementation, for instance FPC + Lazarus: these are very complete, well documented and comparable in power to Delphi, the modern Pascal-based development environment.  Btw, when you say "silible", do you actually mean "symbol", like `hp`, `x` and `y`?

Comment: I don't know PascalABC.NET, but a syntax like `save(...)=save.txt` is very unlikely to be correct in any Pascal I know. I could imagine that `save('hp=30,x=3,y=74,mode=7', `save.txt`);` could work, **if there is a procedure for that, in your Pascal** (I actually doubt it). But I assume you will have to use Pascal I/O, i.e. using Writeln or similar, or something that .NET provides, e.g. streams and a text writer.